# How to use execute statement in mysql while using dynamic where clause

Tags: asp.net, mysql

```
Below is my store procedure .please help........



BEGIN



DECLARE selectQuery VARCHAR(2000);
declare finalquery varchar(2000);
declare stmt3 varchar(2000);

SET selectQuery = 'SELECT tbl_property.intId, strAddressLine1,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountyTypeId) as strCountyName ,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountryTypeId) as strCountryName ,strpostCode,(tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.floatAskingPrice),tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intBedrooms
FROM tbl_property LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria on tbl_property.intId = tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intPro
set finalquery =CONCAT(selectQuery,strSqlQuery,' AND tbl_property.intId=1 ');  

execute finalquery;

END
```

when i run the store procedure and passes the parameter 'where tbl_property.intId=1' it gives the Procedure execution failed
1243 - Unknown prepared statement handler (finalquery) given to EXECUTE

well i check the query result by select statement it gives the correct query and return result.So please help me in using the Execute statement.

Comment: SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 2):

Thanxs for your help, I have tried it and it works with little modifications..below is my store procedure:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE selectQuery VARCHAR(2000);
declare finalquery varchar(2000);

SET selectQuery = 'SELECT tbl_property.intId, strAddressLine1,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountyTypeId) as strCountyName ,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountryTypeId) as strCountryName ,strpostCode,(tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.floatAskingPrice),tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intBedrooms
FROM tbl_property LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria on tbl_property.intId = tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intProId ';

set @finalquery =CONCAT(selectQuery,strSqlQuery,' AND tbl_property.intId=1 ');  

PREPARE result from @finalquery;
EXECUTE result;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE result;

END
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer when the system lets you, or edit this into your question and accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: and indicate what you have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html, it may help you ,
BEGIN

```
DECLARE selectQuery VARCHAR(2000);
declare finalquery varchar(2000);
declare stmt3 varchar(2000);

SET selectQuery = 'SELECT tbl_property.intId, strAddressLine1,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountyTypeId) as strCountyName ,(select strItemName from tbl_lk_item where intId=tbl_property.intPropertyCountryTypeId) as strCountryName ,strpostCode,(tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.floatAskingPrice),tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intBedrooms
FROM tbl_property LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria on tbl_property.intId = tbl_pro_adver_matchcriteria.intProId ';

set finalquery =CONCAT(selectQuery,strSqlQuery);  


EXECUTE finalquery;
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic statement has to be prepared and deallocated after use. Here is an example.

```
BEGIN

SET @selectQuery = 'SELECT * from table1 where'

SET @QUERY = CONCAT(@selectQuery, ' field = 1');            
SELECT @QUERY;
PREPARE s FROM @QUERY;

EXECUTE s;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;

END
```